# Difference of cp1251 and cp10007 python to encode/decode russian symbols

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I make a program that identifies encoding of text. I have encoding list and for each encoding I open the file with that encoding and perform frequency analysis, then I compare frequencies and find the encoding. I need to identifiy cp10007 too, if I understood it right, cp10007 is mac-cyrillic, but cp1251 and mac-cyrillic have bytes for coding russian symbols. However if I decode mac-cyrillic(cp10007) like cp1251 to utf-8, I have a wrong decoding in a few symbols. How can I find differences between 10007 and cp1251?

Comment: Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Cyrillic_encoding . Or do just a python script which convert all 256 byte values into UTF-8 string (decoding the first file with the two encoders), so now you get the decoding directly from python

Comment: A bit unclear _if i decode mac-cyrillic(cp10007) like cp1251 to utf-8, i have wrong decoding in a few symbols_. Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].